# Dlib installed to local conda directory and not system directory

Tags: python, pip, conda, archlinux, dlib

I am trying to install dlib on my conda environment. When I install the package, it gets installed in ".local" folder and not on my conda environment. I am using arch linux and am unable to solve this problem for a week now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
(landmarks) [aastha@lenovo face-detection]$ pip install dlib 
Requirement already satisfied: dlib in /home/aastha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.19.0)
```

Comment: Could you post the result by `pip freeze |grep dlib`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in [the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) this is the default location for installation of packages by pip **within** an activated conda environment (in your case it is likely called `landmarks`).

You would have to leave the environment and install using `sudo`:

```
conda deactivate
sudo pip install dlib
```

Even then in the conda environment the local installation will be the primary one. If you do not want that then you have uninstall it *before* deactivating the conda environment.

```
pip uninstall -y dlib
```